# Bootstrap scrollable table with fixed header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I want to create a table with a lot of data. To keep it all sorted out, I want the table to be scrollable. I use bootstrap to pimp up the table.
I know this question is asked before and the solution does work for me, but my table is a mess. See the table on the right for what it looks like. I want it to look more like the table to the left.

[image]

I can fix this table by manually correcting the width and height of each <"tr"> and <"td"> element, but there must be a better way of doing this.

```css
.alignmentp {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead>tr>th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Speciale tarieven buiten 's-Herogenbosch</h3>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <span class="clickable filter" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Klik om te zoeken" data-container="body">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel-body">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task-table-filter" data-action="filter" data-filters="#task-table" placeholder="Zoek naar een plaats.." />
  </div>
  
  <table class="table table-hover table-fixed" id="task-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Van</th>
        <th>Naar</th>
        <th>Normaal</th>
        <th>Onze prijs</th>
        <th>Korting</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="alignmentp">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>'s-Hertogenbosch</td>
        <td>Ammerzoden</td>
        <td>€ 35,00-</td>
        <td>€ 24,99-</td>
        <td>30 %</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `text-align: left !important;` from `.alignmentp`?

Comment: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/readme.md

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer. It was helpful for me.

```css
table.table-fixedheader {
  width: 100%;
}

table.table-fixedheader,
table.table-fixedheader>thead,
table.table-fixedheader>tbody,
table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr,
table.table-fixedheader>tbody>tr,
table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr>th,
table.table-fixedheader>tbody>td {
  display: block;
}

table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr:after,
table.table-fixedheader>tbody>tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

table.table-fixedheader>tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}

table.table-fixedheader>thead {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table.table-fixedheader>thead::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: inherit;
}

table.table-fixedheader>thead>tr>th:after,
table.table-fixedheader>tbody>tr>td:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table-cell;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

table.table-fixedheader>thead tr th,
table.table-fixedheader>tbody tr td {
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-fixedheader table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="15%">Column1Column1Column1Column1</th>
          <th width="15%">Column2</th>
          <th width="15%">Column3</th>
          <th width="15%">Column4</th>
          <th width="40%">Column5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="height:110px">
        <tr>
          <td width="15%">aaaaaaaaaaa</td>
          <td width="15%">bbbbbbbbbbb</td>
          <td width="15%">ccccccccccc</td>
          <td width="15%">ddddddddddd</td>
          <td width="40%">eeeeeeeeeee</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, but it does not support responsiveness. On full-screen the table looks good, but when I resize the window, everything gets messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are having problems with your columns not lining up. What you could do is find out how wide your widest element is (`<td>` or `<th>`) and then set *all* `<td>` and `<th>` elements to that width.

Another possible solution is to add the `table-responsive` class to your table, as defined in the [Bootstrap table docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables), and make the width of your `<td>` and `<th>` elements be defined by how many there are in a row. If there are five `<td>`s in a `<tr>`, set the width of the `<td>`s to be 20%.

Hope this fixed your problem, if not, just comment below and I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fixHeader {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.fixHeader th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #b4bab4;
}

.fixHeader table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixHeader th,
.fixHeader td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="fixHeader" style="height:200px;">
  <table class="table card-border">
    <thead class="tableHead">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">
          <label class="form-check-label">xyz</label>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"> abc</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of listData">
        <td>
          <div class="form-check">
            {{item.Name}}
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="form-check-label">{{ item.Value }}</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```